# Running ./bin/magento support:backup:db give me an error

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, database

I'm try to run Magento Command

```
./bin/magento support:backup:code 
./bin/magento support:backup:db
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Error: Utility mysqldump not found
```

the MySql Server is in deferent than Magento 2 server

I try to install mysqldump but I get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package mysqldump
```

is there any way to run this command in magento 2 web servers and mysql database in another server.

Comment: Did you try to install mysqldump on your MySQL Server? Also, what OS is the MySQL server on?

Comment: HI Maddy thank your for reply I thank it is already installed because when I type   mysqldump in to CLI I get command option or it have to install separately, I was looking for to install it separately but I could not find anything about install mysqldump separately, and I use Ubuntu 14.04 for MySql Server OS

Comment: Could be a permission issue. Check if db user has permission to run mysqldump. or if the user that is running the commands on shell has  permission to execute mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the issue by install mysql-client-5.6 in Magento web Server and after that everything is working fine 
thank you all for your time and help
Salim Hussein